# Merge and group array of object without duplicate

Tags: javascript, lodash

I had a lists of duplicate array of objects. Each of them had different property. I want to group the property into one particular object of array uniquely without duplication of array object. If can done in lodash library, it would be awesome.

**Data**

```
[  
   {  
      "mc":{  
         "id":"mc-id1"
      },
      "meal":{  
         "id":32,
         "mc_id":"mc-id1",
         "name":"BulletProof Vanilla"
      }
   },
   {  
      "mc":{  
         "id":"mc-id1",
      },
      "meal":{  
         "id":31,
         "mc_id":"mc-id1",
         "name":"Olive oil"
      }
   },
   {  
      "mc":{  
         "id":"mc-id2"
      },
      "meal":{  
         "id":38,
         "mc_id":"mc-id2",
         "name":"Organic fish tail"
      }
   },
   {  
      "mc":{  
         "id":"mc-id2"
      },
      "meal":{  
         "id":37,
         "mc_id":"mc-id2",
         "name":"Organic fish head"
      }
   }
]
```

**Expected Output**

```
[  
   {  
      "mc":{  
         "id":"mc-id1"
      },
      "meal":[{  
         "id":32,
         "mc_id":"mc-id1",
         "name":"BulletProof Vanilla"
      },{
      "meal":{  
         "id":31,
         "mc_id":"mc-id1",
         "name":"Olive oil"
      }]
   },
   {  
      "mc":{  
         "id":"mc-id2"
      },
      "meal":[{  
         "id":38,
         "mc_id":"mc-id2",
         "name":"Organic fish tail"
      },{  
         "id":37,
         "mc_id":"mc-id2",
         "name":"Organic fish head"
      }]
   }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I use groupby, first and map to get the desired output.

```js
var array = [  
    {  
       "mc":{  
          "id":"mc-id1"
       },
       "meal":{  
          "id":32,
          "mc_id":"mc-id1",
          "name":"BulletProof Vanilla"
       }
    },
    {  
       "mc":{  
          "id":"mc-id1",
       },
       "meal":{  
          "id":31,
          "mc_id":"mc-id1",
          "name":"Olive oil"
       }
    },
    {  
       "mc":{  
          "id":"mc-id2"
       },
       "meal":{  
          "id":38,
          "mc_id":"mc-id2",
          "name":"Organic fish tail"
       }
    },
    {  
       "mc":{  
          "id":"mc-id2"
       },
       "meal":{  
          "id":37,
          "mc_id":"mc-id2",
          "name":"Organic fish head"
       }
    }
 ];
    var array = _.groupBy(array, function(o){
   return o.mc.id;
 })

 array = _.map(array, function(o){
   return {
     mc : _.first(o).mc,
     meal: _.map(o, function(p){
     return p.meal
   })
   }
 })

 console.log(array)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

As a horrible one liner (assuming your input is in a variable called data):

```
_.map(_.groupBy(data, (o) => o.mc.id), (i, k) => {return {mc: k, meal: _.map(i, (m) => m.meal)}})
```

a slightly more detailed approach:

```
var groupedByMc = _.groupBy(data, (obj) => obj.mc.id)
var output = _map(groupedByMc, (obj, key) => {
    return { 
        mc: key, 
        meal: _.map(obj, m) => m.meal 
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You can use [`lodash#groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) to group each item in the array by `mc.id`.
2. Use [`lodash#mapValues`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#mapValues) with a partially created [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#groupBy) function using [`lodash#partial`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial) to associate each `mc.id` by their `meals`.
3. Convert the `mc.id` key and `meal` object into an array of key-value pair using [`lodash#toPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#toPairs). e.g. `{a:1, b:2}` will be `[['a', '1'],['b', '2']]`.
4. Use [`lodash#map`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#map) with a partially created [`lodash#zipObjectDeep`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#zipObjectDeep) function using [`lodash#partial`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#partial) to assicate the key-value pair array into their respective keys: `mc.id` and `meal`.

---

```
var result = _(array)
  // group each item by mc.id key
  .groupBy('mc.id') 
  // associate each mc.id by all of the grouped meals
  .mapValues(_.partial(_.map, _, 'meal')) 
  // convert key-value into an array pair values
  .toPairs()
  // associate the array values into their respective keys
  .map(_.partial(_.zipObjectDeep, ['mc.id', 'meal']))
  // get the value
  .value();
```

```js
var array = [{
    "mc": {
      "id": "mc-id1"
    },
    "meal": {
      "id": 32,
      "mc_id": "mc-id1",
      "name": "BulletProof Vanilla"
    }
  },
  {
    "mc": {
      "id": "mc-id1",
    },
    "meal": {
      "id": 31,
      "mc_id": "mc-id1",
      "name": "Olive oil"
    }
  },
  {
    "mc": {
      "id": "mc-id2"
    },
    "meal": {
      "id": 38,
      "mc_id": "mc-id2",
      "name": "Organic fish tail"
    }
  },
  {
    "mc": {
      "id": "mc-id2"
    },
    "meal": {
      "id": 37,
      "mc_id": "mc-id2",
      "name": "Organic fish head"
    }
  }
];

var result = _(array)
  // group each item by mc.id key
  .groupBy('mc.id') 
  // associate each mc.id by all of the grouped meals
  .mapValues(_.partial(_.map, _, 'meal')) 
  // convert key-value into an array pair values
  .toPairs()
  // associate the array values into their respective keys
  .map(_.partial(_.zipObjectDeep, ['mc.id', 'meal']))
  // get the value
  .value();
  
console.log(result);
```

```css
body > div { min-height: 100%; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.4/lodash.min.js"></script>
```